# Countable dense subsets of a separable Hilbert space, in a dense subspace

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that $H$ is a separable Hilbert space. 
Is it true that any dense vector subspace $V$ of $H$ contains a countable subset  $A$ that is dense in $H$ ?

Comment: In general, any dense subset $S$ of a second-countable topological space (such as separable metric spaces) admits a countable dense subset.

Comment: Thank you, is there a reference for such result ?

Comment: Pick a countable basis $\mathcal U$. $S$ intersects all the elements of $\mathcal U$. So we can choose elements $s_U\in S\cap U$ for each $U\in\mathcal U$. The set $A=\{s_U\,:\,U\in\mathcal U\}$ is dense because it intersects all the elements of $\mathcal U$.